# OLS estimator solved by matrix

Tags: matrices, statistics, solution-verification, economics, parameter-estimation

I'm still confused.
If I have the model:
$y = β_1x_1 + β_2x_2 + u$.
I have to show that the OLS estimator is:

[image]

I think that I have to use $\beta =\begin{pmatrix}
\beta_1 \\
\beta_2
\end{pmatrix}=(X^tX)^{-1}X^tY$. But I'm a bit confused.
Now I think that:
$$
X = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}   x_{11} & x_{12} \\  \vdots & \vdots \\  x_{n1} & x_{n2} \end{array} \right]. \qquad\qquad  Y = \left[ \begin{array}{c} y_1 \\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{array} \right].
$$. And if I find $(X^tX):$
$$
X^tX = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}   \sum_{i} X_{i1}X_{i1} & \sum_{i} X_{i1}X_{i2} \\   \sum_{i} X_{i1}X_{i2} & \sum_{i} X_{i2}X_{i2} \end{array} \right]. \qquad\qquad  
$$.
But I can't find $(X^tX)^{-1}$ because $\frac{1}{ad-bc}$ and the
the denominator in the fraction will give $0$? What can I do in stead???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $$
X^tX = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}   \sum_{i} X_{i1}X_{i1} & \sum_{i} X_{i1}X_{i2} \\   \sum_{i} X_{i1}X_{i2} & \sum_{i} X_{i2}X_{i2} \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}   \sum_{i} X^2_{i1} & \sum_{i} X_{i1}X_{i2} \\   \sum_{i} X_{i1}X_{i2} & \sum_{i} X^2_{i2}\end{array} \right]. \qquad\qquad  
$$

Then $$det(X^tX) = \left( \sum_{i} X^2_{i1}\right)\left(\sum_{i} X^2_{i2}\right) - \left(\sum_{i} X_{i1}X_{i2}\right)^2$$
which I don't see why should be zero.
Then using:
$$
(X^tX)^{-1} = \frac{1}{det(X^tX)} \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}   \sum_{i} X^2_{i2} & - \sum_{i} X_{i1}X_{i2} \\   -\sum_{i} X_{i1}X_{i2} & \sum_{i} X^2_{i1} \end{array} \right]. \qquad\qquad  
$$
leads to the expected result for $\beta_1$.